# Creating new symbols with full font-metrics and vector quality

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, symbols, matplotlib

*(Note: this question is similar to quite a few others on SO (e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150412/creating-text-symbols-with-tikz), [that one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351256/latex-special-character-%E2%88%9F/351289#351289), [that other one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552235/creating-a-new-symbol-in-latex), ... but I could find none discussing the explicit need for the new symbols to have proper font metrics attached.)*

Dear Hive Mind,

I need/want to use LaTeX to include custom symbols in Python (`matplotlib`) plots.

I initially used `metafont` to create the symbols, but ended up using `tikz` instead to get vector quality symbols, and packed them up in a dedicated LaTeX package. This works perfectly from the LaTeX perspective. However, I [eventually learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769147/tikzpicture-cropped-from-dvi-when-used-in-matplotlib-plt-text) that `matplotlib` requires proper font metrics for elements to be displayed correctly in the figure text elements.

**Hence this question:** what would be the proper/cleanest way to create new LaTeX symbols *with full font metric* ?

Can I still use `tikz` and add the font metric info to it ? Do I need to create a full vector font instead ? What would be the 2021 best tool to do so ? Is `pict2e` what I am looking for ?

**Edit 23.08.2021**: `pict2e` (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203710/how-to-create-new-symbol-like-shown-in-figure/203714)) does not solve the problem with the font metrics.

**Note 23.08.2021**: I have started looking closely at FontForge, but have [encountered some issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611746/create-font-package-to-use-custom-vectorial-symbols-via-fontforge).

For the record, here's a simplified excerpt of my `tikz` code inside the `.dtx` file:

```
%    \begin{macrocode}
\tikzset{my style/.style={line width=0.2ex, radius=1ex, baseline=-0.6ex}}

%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \noindent Next, each symbol is being defined individually.
%
% \begin{macro}{\firstsymbol}
% The first symbol:
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\firstsymbol}{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[my style]
   \draw  (0, 0) circle;
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Comment: what happens if you add some text to the circle, e.g. tiny periods at the bottom left and the top right of the circle?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: do you mean around the `\tikzpicture` structure inside the `\newcommand` entity ?

Comment: I mean inside the tikzpicture, add some `\node{.}`. Does matplotlib then show the dot and the circle?

Comment: No, `matplotlib` only shows (on-screen) the text of the node (if I save using the `pgf` backend, it all works fine of course). If I ask the node to have (e.g.) a green circle around it with `node[circle, draw=green] {.}`, it still only shows the text of the node.

Comment: that sounds as if you will have to create a proper font, e.g. with fontforge.

Comment: I’ve l[embedded a SVG into a rescaled box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579973/61644) before, and you could adapt this technique to a TikZ vector image. It’d probably be simpler to scale to `\baselineskip`.

Comment: Or select a scaling factor with `\mathchoice`.

Comment: @Davislor: thanks for the suggestion. But --unless I missed something ?-- I still can't get font metrics (that `matplotlib` requires to display the `tikzpicture`) that way. For the scaling, I was already drawing the symbols the the correct *text scale* using ex units. Did you mean something different ?

Comment: @fpavogt Ah, sorry. You’ve got the LaTeX side working correctly, I see, and you’re asking about a different piece of software. Have you tried putting the symbols into a font, with FontForge?

Comment: @Davislor: I have downloaded but not yet tried FontForge. Since the symbols I need are highly parametrizable, `tikz` was ideal to draw them with no fuss,  without having to deal with the whole "font" Universe ... But since I end up needing proper font metrics, I guess there's no by-passing this ... ?

Comment: You might be able to do it as a variable font? I believe `fontspec` now supports those.

Answer (score 1):

Two years down the line, and the solution has taken the [following form](https://github.com/MeteoSwiss/metsymb).

Essentially, I draw the symbols using TikZ, then create an OpenType font with the resulting SVGs using FontForge, before bundling it into a LaTeX package.

The resulting package was uploaded to [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/metsymb).